Emacs Org-babel executing GForth code freezes Emacs
I'm trying to execute a GForth source block in org mode. But as soon as I try executing the Forth code block, Emacs stops responding.
What I'm trying to do:
I wrote in my Org block:
#+begin_src forth
1 2 .s
#+end_src

and pressed C-c C-c, then it says "Executing Forth code block at position 407...". And then Emacs just 'froze'. It simply stopped responding to any command.
Expected Output:
1 2 ok 2
What I did for configuration:
I'm currently using:

WSL Ubuntu 22.04
gforth 0.7.9_20240215 amd64
Emacs 30.0.50, built from source
Org mode 9.6.1

I mostly followed the instruction in:
https://gforth.org/manual/Installing-gforth_002eel.html .

I used ob-forth library, and downloaded gforth.el code at: https://github.com/forthy42/gforth/blob/master/gforth.el

I renamed 'gforth.el' to 'ext:gforth.el', since in ob-forth it declares:


(declare-function forth-proc "ext:gforth" ())


I put 'ext:gforth.el' in ~/emacs.d/lisp/ directory, which is included in my load path.

I tested forth-mode provided in 'ext:gforth.el'. I ran M-x run-forth beforehand. When I tried executing code in scratch buffer with forth-mode activated, everything worked and the result showed up in the minibuffer.


My init.el:
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((forth . t)))

(require 'ob-forth)
(load-file "~/.emacs.d/lisp/ext:gforth.el")
(autoload 'forth-mode "ext:gforth.el")
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.fs\\'" . forth-mode) 
                auto-mode-alist))
(autoload 'forth-block-mode "ext:gforth.el")
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.fb\\'" . forth-block-mode) 
                auto-mode-alist))
(add-hook 'forth-mode-hook (function (lambda ()
   ;; customize variables here:
   (setq forth-indent-level 4)
   (setq forth-minor-indent-level 2)
   (setq forth-hilight-level 3)
   ;;; ...
)))

Any advice would be appreciated!

Turns out the problem was in org-babel-forth-session-execute in ob-forth.el.gz.
(defun org-babel-forth-session-execute (body params)
  (require 'forth-mode)
  (let ((proc (forth-proc))
    (rx " \\(\n:\\|compiled\n\\|ok\n\\)")
    (result-start))
    (with-current-buffer (process-buffer (forth-proc))
      (mapcar (lambda (line)
        (setq result-start (progn (goto-char (process-mark proc))
                      (point)))
        (comint-send-string proc (concat line "\n"))
        ;; wait for forth to say "ok"
        (while (not (progn (goto-char result-start)
                   (re-search-forward rx nil t)))
          (accept-process-output proc 0.01))
        (let ((case (match-string 1)))
          (cond
           ((string= "ok\n" case)
            ;; Collect intermediate output.
            (buffer-substring (+ result-start 1 (length line))
                      (match-beginning 0)))
           ((string= "compiled\n" case))
           ;; Ignore partial compilation.
           ((string= "\n:" case)
            ;; Report errors.
            (org-babel-eval-error-notify 1
                                         (buffer-substring
                                          (+ (match-beginning 0) 1) (point-max)))
            nil))))
          (split-string (org-trim
                 (org-babel-expand-body:generic body params))
                "\n"
                'omit-nulls)))))

The regex catches "ok\n", but not "ok". If you evaluate 1 2 .s, gforth will print "<2> 1 2  ok 2", and the regex search will fail, so the whole thing stops.
I redefined org-babel-forth-session-execute to catch "ok" in my init.el:
;;...
(rx " \\(\n:\\|compiled\n\\|ok\\)")
;;...
((string= "ok" case)

Now everything works fine.

Please report it with M-x org-submit-bug-report - thanks!
